# Bootstrap display number of elements in row based on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, media-queries

I need to display 3 images in a row if user is on medium sized devices (≥768px) and if they're on (<768px) devices, then I need to display 2 images in a row. How do I do this using Bootstrap or plain flex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of Bootstrap columns:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

If you want to do it yourself, best practices would have you place the <768px code outside of a media queries and the >768px inside of one, that way the page is "mobile-first."

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <img class="flex-image" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
    <img class="flex-image" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
    <img class="flex-image" src="example.com/example.jpg"/>
</div>
```

--

```
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-image {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-image {
        flex: 0 0 33%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use of `*-device-width`,like this**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:767px) {
  .contImg {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width:768px) { 
  .contImg {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contImg {
  float: left;
}

.contImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:767px) {
  .contImg {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width:768px) { 
  .contImg {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contImg">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w">
</div>

<div class="contImg">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA">
</div>

<div class="contImg">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeY54SaYkaOxxyXlu_ng21EMIBZvJjnZBNQAOsIh_0_6Tvu9et">
</div>
```